# Comparar el primer caracter del texto

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo un código, que si a una función se le da como parámetro la string:

```
#elemento
```

Usará un `document.getElementById();`

y si recibe la string de la forma:

```
.elemento
```

Usará un `getElementsByClassName();`

Pero el problema es, ¿qué hago cuando envien "#."? Sería conveniente que se tomara en cuenta solamente el primer caracter, entonces pensé en hacer:

```
if(parametro.substr(0,1) == "#" ) { //Hacer algo }
```

Y funcionaría, pero ¿cómo podría hacerlo con una expresión regular?

Comment: ¿Para qué una expresión regular si obtener el primer caracter es más eficiente, más claro, más fácil de mantener, mucho mejor? Podrías usar `if (parametro[0] == '#')` si te interesa acortarlo.

Comment: Además, para qué reinventar una función que ya existe: [document.querySelector(parametro)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Más que un fin, es para conocer más allá

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comenté, jamás usaría regex para algo que se puede solucionar sencillo:

```
if (parametro[0] == '#') {
    // ...
}
```

Ni para reinventar una función que ya existe: [`document.querySelector(parametro)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Pero, como te interesa para aprender...

En regex, `^` es una aserción que coincide con el inicio del string (o de la línea si se usa un modificador). Como toda aserción, no coincide con un caracter, sino con **una posición** que cumple la condición.

Así, podemos utilizar `^` para garantizar que coincida con el inicio y luego con el caracter deseado. La expresión quedaría:

```
/^#/
```

- *Un `#` al inicio del texto.*

Código:

```js
function esId(parametro) {
    return /^#/.test(parametro);
}

//Pruebas
console.log(esId("#abc"));  //true
console.log(esId(".#def")); //false
console.log(esId("#.ghi")); //true
```

Más información en [Expresiones Regulares (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-caret).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Marino

Answer (score 0):

El objetivo aparente es detectar el primer caracter, pero yo veo un problema de fondo, y es detectar los nombres de las variables.

Para esto, lo que hago es, además de mirar el primer caracter, mirar que el segundo no sea un número, y además aceptar otros caracteres como guión bajo y signo pesos.

Estos caracteres son los más comunes, pero al momento de probar, puede aceptar hasta carácteres unicode. No voy a entrar en eso ya que es complicado, pero dejo una solución aproximada.

Una variable no puede empezar con un número, y lo siguiente puede ser un número, letras, o lo que sea, siempre que no se tope con los caracteres especiales del lenguaje.

- Para que no sea un número el primer caracter de la variable: `[^0-9]`
- Para que sea una letra: `[a-z]`
- Un número: `\d`
- Un punto: `\.`... Aquí hay que tener cuidado, porque el punto en algunos lenguajes es como un comodín, es decir, acepta cualquier cosa.
- Almohadilla (para este caracter no hay truco): `#`.

```js
var nombre_variable="[^0-9][a-z\\d_$]{0,}"
new RegExp(nombre_variable,"i")
var almohadilla=new RegExp("^#"+nombre_variable+"$")
var propiedad=new RegExp("^\."+nombre_variable+"$")
console.log(almohadilla)
console.log(propiedad)

var pruebas=[
  "variable_8", "3_a"
]
for(var i in pruebas){

  console.log( "."+pruebas[i]+" "+
    propiedad.test("."+pruebas[i])
  )
  console.log( "#"+pruebas[i]+" "+
    propiedad.test("#"+pruebas[i])
  )
}
```

Comment: Está muy bien agregar condiciones para garantizar un nombre válido. Sin embargo, en [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) se permite *cualquier caracter que no sea un espacio*. Siguiendo esa condición, la expresión regular sería `/^#\S+/`.

Comment: @Mariano Tienes razón, es una variable de HTML y no de JavaScript... Bueno, no me sale esa expresión regular.

Comment: Lo que habías intentado estaba bien... Sólo que tiene un problema: `[^0-9]` coincide con un espacio, por lo que tomaría como válido algo como `"# . # ."` (que no lo es).

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo necesitas validar que no ingresen "#.", si es así con la siguiente expresión regular puedes validar y ejecutar alguna condición de error.

```
var str="#.element";
var a = str.match(/\#\./);
if(a) {
    // condición de error
    alert(a);
}
```